# gparted issue on raspberry pi Kali

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a 128gb mSD card in my Pi3b+ running Kali(pi version).  I wanted to expand the FS so I installed gparted and followed the steps.  After applying the resize, this is what I got.  The partition is expanded but the area remains unuseable (grey portion).

[image: Gparted on Kali for Pi]

Also, I am no longer able to make edits to the FS.  It will not allow any modifications.

My goal is to be able to use the entire disk with the system.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, turns out I just needed to shake out the cob webs.

Partition editing is not allowed on a mounted drive...

I removed the SD, put it in another linux machine and ran a check on the FS.  The FS now uses the entire disk and it is all accessible.  Sorry for the oversight.